# Create two or many table in SQLite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to create several tables in my SQLite database but I am faced with an error that I do not understand.

Here is the image that clearly illustrates what I see on my screen

[image]

Here's my code I do not know what's wrong with it. help please

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    createTable(database);// Crear la tabla "gasto"
}
private void createTable(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String cmd = "CREATE TABLE " + EventProvider.YAFE + " (" +
            EventProvider.Column._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            EventProvider.Column.TITRE + " TEXT, " +
            EventProvider.Column.DATE + " TEXT, " +
            EventProvider.Column.IMAGE + " TEXT," +
            EventProvider.Column.ID_R + " TEXT UNIQUE," +
            EventProvider.Column.STATUT + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT "+ EventProvider.STATUT_OK+"," +
            EventProvider.Column.INSERTION_EN_ATTENTE + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)";
    database.execSQL(cmd);

    String table_stand = "CREATE_TABLE_STAND" + EventProvider.STAND + "(" +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand.TITRE_STAND + "TEXT," +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand.IMAGE_STAND + "TEXT," +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand.ID_R_STAND + "TEXT, UNIQUE" +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand.STATUT_STAND + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT" + EventProvider.STATUT_OK + "," +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand.INSERTION_EN_ATTENTE_STAND + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)";
    database.execSQL(table_stand);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try {
        db.execSQL("drop table " + EventProvider.YAFE);
        db.execSQL("drop table_stand" + EventProvider.STAND);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
    }
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: what is the error? BTW, do you know what a *screenshot* is?

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko when I put the cursor on the underlined line in red I get these two error `<statement> expected, got 'CREATE_TABLEyafe` and `INDEX, TABLE, TRIGGER or VIEW expected,
got, 'stand_yafe'`

Comment: looks like you need to learn some SQL basics before you continue. About how to create and delete tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change in createTable()**

```
       String table_stand = "CREATE TABLE " + EventProvider.STAND + "(" +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand.TITRE_STAND + "TEXT," +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand.IMAGE_STAND + "TEXT," +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand.ID_R_STAND + "TEXT, UNIQUE" +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand.STATUT_STAND + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT" + EventProvider.STATUT_OK + "," +
            EventProvider.ColumnStand.INSERTION_EN_ATTENTE_STAND + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)";
```

**Change in onUpgrade()**

```
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EventProvider.YAFE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EventProvider.STAND);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of this "CREATE_TABLE_STAND"

try this "CREATE TABLE STAND"

Answer (score 0):

```
Here change "CREATE_TABLE_STAND" to CREATE TABLE TableName



String table_stand = "CREATE_TABLE_STAND" + EventProvider.STAND + "(" +
        EventProvider.ColumnStand._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
   *emphasized text*     EventProvider.ColumnStand.TITRE_STAND + "TEXT," +
        EventProvider.ColumnStand.IMAGE_STAND + "TEXT," +
        EventProvider.ColumnStand.ID_R_STAND + "TEXT, UNIQUE" +
        EventProvider.ColumnStand.STATUT_STAND + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT" + EventProvider.STATUT_OK + "," +
        EventProvider.ColumnStand.INSERTION_EN_ATTENTE_STAND + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)";
database.execSQL(table_stand);
```